# Error send mail django en shell

Tags: python, django

tengo un error en el terminal shell en django, ya que estoy tratando de probar enviando un correo, tengo activado en gmail la opcion para recibir y enviar correos de aplicaciones de terceros pero aun asi tengo un problema, el mensaje que me arroja es :"ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión", busque solucion pero no encuentro nada que me ayude...

```
from decouple import config

EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOTS='smtp.googlemail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='gmail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('USER_MAIL_PASSWORD')
```

obviamente tengo puesto en host_user mi correo

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail("Subject here", "Here is the message", "examplefrom@gmail.com", ["exampleto@gmail.com"], fail_silently=False,)
```

y ese es lo que coloco en la shell

Comment: Estas seguro que no es EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' ?

Comment: lo he probado de las dos formas la verdad se me olvido comentarlo, pero aun asi no me funciona correctamente..

Comment: Tambien aqui si mal no recuerdo EMAIL_HOST_USER='gmail' aqui va tu email example@gmail.com

Comment: Si abajo lo dice "obviamente tengo puesto en host_user mi correo", aún no he podido y no entiendo como eh visto videos y todo pero aún asi

Comment: Tienes habilitado el two step verification en esa cuenta?

Comment: two step verification?, yo tenia entendido que tenias que tener activado el acceso de las aplicaciones poco seguras, pero si no es asi porfavor confirmame para habilitar la verificacion en dos pasos..

Comment: Es correcto solo tienes que tener habilitado el acceso de las aplicaciones, habilitar el two step en algún momento me dio problemas por eso preguntaba.

Comment: Lo ultimo que se me ocurre es que tengas tus settings separados y por eso no pueda accederlos cuando usas  ```python manage.py shell```  para eso usa ```python manage.py shell --settings=tus_settings```

Comment: lo intente y me arroga un error :D, pero yo tenia entendido que si estaba enlazado los settings ya que abro el shell desde el cd del proyecto en si, entonces no encuentro alguna explicacion logica el porque no me realiza el envio del mail

Comment: si pudieras poner la estructura de tu proyecto o el nuevo error seria de ayuda

Comment: conseguiste resolverlo? Tengo el mismo error y no doy con la solución. Gracias! un saludo.

Comment: no aun no lo consigo, le acabo de preguntar a una persona que es cercana y tiene experiencia pero aun no me responde, cualquier cosa lo subo aqui

Comment: Si alguien quiere ver un poco más amplio para poder ayudarme en el problema lo tengo subido en GitHub si quieren clonar el proyecto
https://github.com/zokn/DjangoCode.git

Answer (score 0):

En la parte que dice EMAIL_HOST_USER='gmail' aqui va tu correo electronico y aqui EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD  , tu contraseña no obstante para envios de correo tienes que activar la opcion Acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras para que asi puedas enviar correos

Comment: Si en comentarios anteriores ya lo habia mencionado que tengo activo esa opcion pero aun asi me tira el error ya sea en shell o en la views